# Cannot insert into field with primary key constraint in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have a "raw" table that looks like this (among other many fields):

```
 team_id |        team_name        
---------+-------------------------
       1 | Team1
       1 | Team1
       2 | Team2
       2 | Team2
```

I want to extract the team names and their id codes and create another table for them, so I created:

```
    CREATE TABLE teams (
        team_id integer NOT NULL,
        team_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT team_pkey PRIMARY KEY (team_id)
);
```

And I am planning to copy the data from the old table to the recently created one like this:

```
INSERT INTO teams(team_id,team_name)                                        
SELECT team_id,team_name FROM rawtable 
GROUP BY team_id, team_name;
```

At first I wasn't adding the `GROUP BY` part, and I was getting a message:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "team_pkey"
```

I added the `GROUP BY` so it doesn't try to insert more than one row for the same team, but the problem still persist and I keep getting the same message.

I don't understand what is causing it. It looks like I am inserting single non duplicate rows into the table. What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure, so it is how you describe. Your data, your SQL is working for me without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two different teams with the same id are in `raw_table` e.g. `(1, 'foo')` and `(1, 'bar')` the `group by` will still return both, because those two *are* different.

If you just want to pick *one* of the rows for duplicate values of `team_id` then you should use something like this:

```
insert into teams (team_id,team_name)  
select distinct on (team_id) team_id, team_name
from rawtable
order by team_id;
```

The Postgres specific `distinct on` operator will make sure that only distinct values for `team_id` are returned.

Comment: Thank you, actually that was the problem I had. I didn't need to change my statement to find the bad row because I accidentally saw it, but I will mark your answer as accepted because of the useful example I can use for the future.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you have the same team_id for more then one team_name at least somewhere in your table. Try to add `Having count(*)=1 to your select statement

Comment: `having count(*) = 1` won't help if two different `team_name` have the same `team_id` because they are still considered different by a `group by team_id, team_name`

Comment: Actually that was it! I didn't copy the original raw table here because it was really long, but it seems that the id column had not been checked for duplicates, so there was one faulty row. I didn't even change the select as you suggest, because I just accidentally saw the offending row....

Comment: Oops, correct. Using max as joachim wrote is a better suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Since the team_id is unique in the destination table, two separate team names with the same id will create duplicates, one row for each name.

A simple fix is to group by team_id so that you only get a single row per id, and pick one of the names the team has (here we somewhat arbitrarily use MAX to get the last in alphabetical order)

```
INSERT INTO teams(team_id,team_name)                                        
 SELECT team_id, MAX(team_name) FROM rawtable 
 GROUP BY team_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use distinct in your query :

> insert into teams (team_id,team_name)   select distinct on (team_id)
>   team_id, team_name from order by team_id;

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT a,b .. and SELECT a,b GROUP BY a, b are equal.

Answer (score 0):

One of your Team1 or Team2 probably has some extra spaces or nonprintable characters. This would cause your group by to return multiple rows for Team_ID 1 or 2 causing the problem.

Comment: This is sample data. For only 2 teams he would have inserted them manually faster then writing the question...

Comment: Er... so was Team1 and Team2 in my example. The point was there could be extra spaces or nonprintable character causing his group by to return multiple rows.